# Disable Missed Call Notifications

Tags: settings, notifications, missed-calls

Is there a way to disable missed call notifications? I haven't found it in any settings on the device, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a trick to disable them. Possibly an app that someone knows of?

Background: I use Google Voice, which also tells me about missed calls. When I miss a call that the phone itself gets, I get a duplicate notification that sticks around until I go into the call log. I don't want to lose the Google Voice notifications, because they also tell me if I missed calls outside of signal range or when the phone is off.

EDIT: I don't think there is a real solution to this, so I have submitted an [Android feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15961). If you are interested in this feature, please go star the issue or post your thoughts.

Comment: Your question just made me realize how bad I want to know how to solve this as well.  I use Voice also, and the duplicate notifications are a total waste of time.

Comment: Yeah, I've done a good amount of searching for it, and haven't really found anything in either settings or apps. I actually kind of doubt there is an easy way to kill them, but I'm hoping someone has a clever way around it.

Comment: What phone are you using?  I never got duplicate missed call notifications on my Moto Droid 1.  Google voice only notified me of Txt messages and voicemails.

Comment: It's something I've enabled in Google Voice. I could turn them off, but the Google Voice notifications are better than the default ones, because it notifies me of calls I miss while off the network.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tasker is a pretty awesome app that basically lets you write little apps/functionality, yourself.

A simple solution, using Tasker, is as follows:

1. Create a new tasked called 'MissedCall'
2. For the '1st context' choose State>Missed Call. Click OK
3. Click Done
4. Task selection, choose New Task
5. Name it 'GetRidOfMissedCalls'. OK
6. Click Add, choose Phone > Call Log. Click Done
7. Click the + button to add another task
8. Choose App > Go Home. Click Done
9. Click Done, again
10. Your task is now setup and you should be in the Tasker profile list, click Apply.

Basically what happens is that when you have a missed call Tasker will open up the Call Log list, which will get rid of the notification, Tasker will then return you to your home screen. 
I assume that most of you missed calls occur when the phone is in your pocket etc. so hopefully the behaviour of returning to the home screen is ok.

*There will be a system flag for missed calls, and if I could find out what it is then we could just get Tasker to switch the flag to false (or missed call count =0), which would be a more elegant solution to the problem.*

Comment: Very interesting...  Please do keep looking into the missed call flag because I would prefer that functionality in case I intentionally miss a call while I'm in the middle of doing something else on my phone.

Comment: I've just checked the list of available system parameters, and missed call is not one of them. There is a parameter that records the last app in use, I could therefore modify the above task to return you to your original app, if that would suffice?

Comment: @ninjaPixel - That would be better, but it would still end up interrupting whatever action the user was performing which isn't ideal.

Comment: That definitely gets me part of the way to a solution, although as JonnyP said, sometimes missed calls happen while I'm actively on the phone. I'm beginning to think a complete disabling like I want may not be possible on Android. I might submit a feature request for it.

Comment: @Jake Basile - You should.  We both should.  There really ought to be a native system option to turn off these notifications rather than forcing people like us to turn to a paid option to work around them.

Comment: @JonnyP - done. I made the request after not finding one already, and edited the question to link to it.

Comment: @ninjaPixel - Can you list the steps you'd use if you wanted Tasker to do this _only_ if the phone is on the home screen or is locked?  In these cases it would be fine to have it return to the home screen after visiting the call log.  I'll award you the full bounty if you can get those steps up in your answer.

Comment: @JonnyP Pretty sure that would just be extra States (step 2). Should be simple to figure out.

Comment: Marking this as answer because I think it's the only real option at the moment, even if it doesn't get all the way there. If you want a full solution, please star the Android issue in the question!

Comment: I think it's in the responsibility of the Google Voice application. If it gives its own notifications, it should clear their copies from the system notifications. Should be given a bug report or enhancement request.

Comment: Can this app be used to suppress the notifications from other scheduled apps?