# How can I tell my device to ignore a public Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wi-fi

The city I live in has city-wide Wi-Fi available for a subscription, but the Wi-Fi access point is public.

This means that everywhere I go in the city I get a notice that there is public Wi-Fi available even though I can't use it because I don't have an account with the city-wide Wi-Fi service.

How can I tell my phone (Droid X, Android 2.2.1, not rooted) to ignore Wi-Fi named "CityWifi"?

I'd like to get notification for other Wi-Fi networks, just not "CityWifi"

Answer (score 5):

You can shut off all open network notifications by going to `Settings -> Wireless and network -> Wi-Fi settings` and unchecking **Network notification**.  Since the notification is system-level, there's no way to leave it enabled and not receive notifications for the one network.  But you could probably do something with Tasker to clear the notification automatically, similar to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7279/disable-missed-call-notifications/7762#7762).

Answer (score 2):

It appears, then, that the answer is "no".

Maybe someone on the Google Android team will see this post (or someone could raise it on the appropriate Google Groups page), and they can include this as an option in a future android release.  Would be easy enough for them to keep a list of SSID and MAC Addresses of APs you want to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Networks that look open but which actually require a subscription are everywhere. You can just turn off notification of public networks altogether -- that's in your Wi-Fi settings.

Otherwise, you may need an app to manage this (I'm on OS 1.6, so I can't speak to what might be built in in later OSs). The market shows a few contenders:

[WifiManager](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.kman.WifiManager&feature=search_result), [WifiPicker](https://market.android.com/details?id=personal.jhjeong.app.WiFiPicker&feature=search_result), [WiFiFoFum](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dynamicallyloaded.wififofum&feature=search_result) are all good starting points.

The best advice I can offer at this stage is that reading through the market is waaay easier on your desktop, since a search for "Wi-Fi" turns up tons of stuff that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd like to get notification for other wifi networks, just not "CityWifi".

Comment: Amanda mentioned some good WiFi managers.  I just tried all three and unfortunately none of them have the features the OP is looking for. Check out [WiFi Ruler](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hogdex.WifiRuler&feature=search_result) - it potentially has the logic you need to block certain APs