# Is there a way to blacklist SSIDs?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell my droid x to ignore a public wifi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/how-can-i-tell-my-droid-x-to-ignore-a-public-wifi-network)

Like, the SSIDs `xfinitywifi` and `timewarnercable` are everywhere near me, and unencrypted, but require a login/password which I don't have.  Is there a way to prevent them from showing up in the list, triggering notifications, etc.?

Comment: +1 This would be useful. I'm often in areas surrounded by "free" wifi that isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blacklisting SSIDs is not currently in the base android software.  It is currently a "Medium" priority Enhancement for Android:  See [Android Issue 7318](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7318)

I have asked a related question ( [How can I tell my device to ignore a public Wi-Fi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/how-can-i-tell-my-droid-x-to-ignore-a-public-wifi-network) ) but haven't found anything that works like I would expect.