# How to block a ssid on my android?

Tags: wi-fi

There ia a suspicious ssid near my house, i want to block the ssid ,not to display on my WiFi Hotspot list,how to set a blacklist on my android phone?
My android version is 4.4.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/how-can-i-tell-my-device-to-ignore-a-public-wi-fi-network

Comment: "*WiFi Hotspot list*" -- what's that?

Comment: Check out this thread on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257034/how-to-hide-ssid-on-android-phone